# get all 4 digit combinations out of a list of strings

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have a list consisting of 4 digit strings (ie: list = ['0000', '1111', ...])
now I want to get a list of all possible 4 digit combinations (w/o rep) for each of these items

This is the code I have using permutations (of course it has repetitions but I will post this one since when I tried combinations it worked really bad)

```
permutes = defaultdict(list)
for item in funo_clean: ## funo_clean is the list with 4 digit numbers
    for permutation in list(itertools.permutations(item)):
        permutes[item].append("".join([str(x) for x in permutation]))
    print ("\n")
```

Also, I don't want the list of combinations to contain the same number I am using to generate it (i.e: if I am using '8800' to generate it this number should not be in the list)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, but results were not good (maybe I am not using it right) that's why I posted the code using permutations since it worked better to my goals.

Comment: Show us what you tried, and explain why the results weren't what you wanted, and maybe we can help.

Comment: only difference is the change in itertools.permutations(item) to itertools.combinations (item, len(item))

but with the permutations code I get, for example:

0647 =>  [0647, 0674, 0467, ...] ## And all possible permutations

with the combinations code I just get one item inside list

0647 => [0647]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set` the permutations:

```
permutes = {}
for item in funo_clean:
    permutes[item] = [''.join(permutation) for permutation in set(itertools.permutations(item))]
    permutes[item].remove(item)
    permutes[item].sort()
```

Comment: I think this gets rid of all reps since if item is '8800' there will be more than one '8800'

Comment: @SJPRO isn't that what you said you wanted?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Yes, I was replying to your "why don't you use next", and I thought he didn't use next because next will get rid only of the first occurence of item. Right?

Comment: @endless I've just changed  "for permutation in list(itertools.permutations(item))" to " for permutation in set(itertools.permutations(item))". Is this practically the same you did, right?

Comment: @SJPRO Yes, but using [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a more pythonic way.

Comment: It should be less expensive (`O(1) vs O(n)`) to remove `item` from `set(permutations(...))` rather than after when it is a list. This would also shorten up that list comprehension by pulling out `set(permutations(...))` into a separate variable (to call `.remove(item)` on).

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce That's indeed a little faster, but consider the whole expensive is `O(n!)` and make the code loosely coupled, get the original permutations first seems better.

Comment: This way you could sort & create the list at the same time though.  https://bpaste.net/show/ebde3d5ba358